# How can I get all the values from a column of a DE?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, lookup

Having the following Data Extension named "RamiroTest", with just two columns Name and Email
[image: DE "EmpleadosTest"]

How can I print only the Email column values?

This is the code I have for the moment, but it's not working...

```
%%[
var @rowCount, @email

set @rowCount  = DataExtensionRowCount("EmpleadosTest")

For @i = 1 to @rowCount do

set @email = Lookup("EmpleadosTest","Email",2,null)

]%%

Email: %%=v(@email)=%%

%%[

Next @i

]%%
```

Comment: Remember to mark my answer as accepted, if it has been helpful

Answer (score 4):

You are very close to getting it right. So, good job so far.
However you need to get your `rowcount` on `LookupRows`, instead of the entire DE.
Also, to get a specific row, from all rows returned by `LookupRows` - you need to use `Row`, and `Field` to get the specific field from that row. So the solution will be something along these lines:

```
%%[
var @rowCount, @email, @emailRowsCount
set @emailRows = LookupRows("EmpleadosTest","return","1")
set @emailRowsCount = RowCount(@emailRows)
for @i = 1 to @emailRowsCount do
]%%

Email: %%=Field(Row(@emailRows,@i),"Email")=%%

%%[
Next @i
]%%
```

Comment: @Ramiro, if you need some variations, there are several outlined here: https://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/